# List of SQL exceptions caused by a Trigger

Tags: c#, sql, exception, triggers

does anyone have a link or know the possible exceptions that can be caused because of a trigger. I am working on a C# application that replicates data to other server, and to make it quicker, I'm using batch  statements. What I have to do is if one statement in the batch fails, it will attempt to recompile a batch and run the rest. Needless to say, this takes FOREVER in the case where the batch is just going to keep failing for whatever reason (such as a broken trigger).

Pretty much the only reason why this would fail in my application is because of something with a trigger(I have NO control over what the triggers look like, so people could have broken ones), so what I would like to do is somehow, from the error message returned after the exception is caught, figure out whether the error is caused by a broken trigger, or invalid/faulty data that caused the trigger to fail (but nothing actually wrong with the trigger itself). If I can deduce that the trigger is just broken, I can stop processing since I know nothing with work.

For example "Error: Invalid object TABLENAME" => Obviously it's the trigger that's broken.

So, basically I'm looking for a list of exceptions (and their error messages) that could be caused by a trigger. If I'm dumb, and every exception can be caused by a trigger, just give me the list of every exception. Thanks

I'm using SQL Server

Comment: are you using MS SQL ?mysql? oracle?

Comment: SQL Server. *meeting minimum length requirement*

Comment: Is there some reason to not use database replication?

Comment: what do you mean by database replication?

Comment: Replication is used to have the same data in two places depending on the requirements it is configured differently: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL SERVER.

Here's where you can get a complete list of errors with triggers.

```
SELECT * FROM sysmessages
WHERE description LIKE '%trigger%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I realized your syntax is wrong (unless SQL later than 2008 has changed it) SELECT * FROM sys.messages where text like '%trigger%'

Comment: also is there a way to filter out the stuff not in English -_-

Comment: Well the query that i mentioned works on SQL Server 2000, 2005,2008, 2008 R2 and 2012. TRIED and TESTED. Works perfectly.

Comment: This will more likely filter out the ones that are not in english:            SELECT * FROM sysmessages
WHERE description LIKE '%trigger%' AND msglangid NOT IN (1033)